# Windows Explorer crashes whenever opening a USB or network drive

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer

**This applies to Windows 7, 64-bit, all Service Packs have been installed.**

Since ~3 months, Windows Exlorer always crashes when I'm connecting to a network drive, or when I'm opening an USB drive. After the crash, it takes ~30 seconds to recover, and then it is stable.

I did some research, and many people say the problem might be connected to shell extension DLLs which automatically are scanning the files on the drive.

But how to detect the faulty DLL and how to disable it?

I found something like `regsvr32 /u shmedia.dll`, but this works only on XP, not on Windows 7.

Comment: Windows Explorer crashes are mostly caused by an incompatible Shell Extension. Please download this [reg file from my SkyDrive](http://cid-128fc518635be2dc.skydrive.live.com/self.aspx/.Public/MS%20Foren/Registry/WER%5E_Explorer_full.reg) and make a double click on the file to import it. If you can't do this, run regedit.exe and import the registry file there! When the Windows Explorer crashes, Windows Error Reporting Service creates a dmp file under C:\Localdumps. Please upload the dump file (compressed 7z or RAR to reduce the size) and post the link here. I take a look at the dump.

Comment: Hello Andre, thank you for your kind offer. Here is a link containing a dump file: https://docs.google.com/folder/d/0BzxwmXCDmjceaTBta2JFZXRZQXM/edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, the Google Drive Tool is the cause:

```
APPLICATION_VERIFIER_HEAPS_DOUBLE_FREE (7)
Heap block already freed.
This situation happens if the block is freed twice. Freed blocks are marked in a
special way and are kept around for a while in a delayed free queue. If a buggy
program tries to free the block again this will be caught assuming the block was not
dequeued from delayed free queue and its memory reused for other allocations.
The depth of the delay free queue is in the order of thousands of blocks therefore
there are good chances that most double frees will be caught. 

ntdll!NtWaitForSingleObject
ntdll!RtlReportExceptionEx
ntdll!RtlReportException
verifier!AVrfpVectoredExceptionHandler
ntdll!RtlpCallVectoredHandlers
ntdll!RtlDispatchException
ntdll!KiUserExceptionDispatch
verifier!VerifierStopMessage
verifier!AVrfpDphReportCorruptedBlock
verifier!AVrfpDphCheckNormalHeapBlock
verifier!AVrfpDphNormalHeapFree
verifier!AVrfDebugPageHeapFree
ntdll!RtlDebugFreeHeap
ntdll! ?? ::FNODOBFM::`string'
ntdll!RtlFreeHeap
verifier!AVrfpRtlFreeHeap
kernel32!HeapFree
verifier!AVrfpHeapFree
msvcr90!free
googledrivesync64!DllCanUnloadNow
shell32!CFSIconOverlayManager::_GetFileOverlayInfo
shell32!CFSIconOverlayManager::GetFileOverlayInfo
shell32!CFSFolder::_GetOverlayInfo
shell32!CFSFolder::GetOverlayIndex
EXPLORERFRAME!CNscOverlayTask::_Extract
EXPLORERFRAME!CNscOverlayTask::InternalResumeRT
EXPLORERFRAME!CRunnableTask::Run
shell32!CShellTask::TT_Run
shell32!CShellTaskThread::ThreadProc
shell32!CShellTaskThread::s_ThreadProc
shlwapi!ExecuteWorkItemThreadProc
ntdll!RtlpTpWorkCallback
ntdll!TppWorkerThread
kernel32!BaseThreadInitThunk
ntdll!RtlUserThreadStart


Loaded symbol image file: googledrivesync64.dll
Image path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Drive\googledrivesync64.dll
Image name: googledrivesync64.dll
Timestamp:        Fri Nov 09 01:56:26 2012 (509C54BA)
CheckSum:         000BED93
ImageSize:        000BB000
File version:     1.6.3837.2778
Product version:  1.6.3837.2778
File flags:       0 (Mask 3F)
File OS:          4 Unknown Win32
File type:        2.0 Dll
File date:        00000000.00000000
Translations:     0409.04b0
CompanyName:      Google
ProductName:      Google Drive
ProductVersion:   1.6.3837.2778
FileVersion:      1.6.3837.2778
FileDescription:  Google Drive shell extension
LegalCopyright:   Google
```

It has issues to display the overlay icons.

**Solution:**
In the Google Drive options, disable the sync overlay icons. This should fix the issue.

If the issue is resolved, run **regedit.exe** again, go to

**HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Windows Error Reporting\LocalDumps**

and

**HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Image File Execution Options**.

Now delete the Explroer.exe key in both keys and reboot. This disables the dump creation and *application verifier*.

Comment: Oh wow, thank you a thousand times !! OK, I now disabled the sync overlay icons, and let's see if it crashes again. Will give feedback again in 1 or 2 days.

Comment: Thank you so much again, yes, this was the solution, explorer is stable now!

Comment: @Georg Scholz Nice to hear that. Did you register to my site? Look in the FAQ section, It shows how you can analyze the dump yourself. And remember to delete both registry keys.

Answer (score 0):

I uninstalled USB drivers but that didn't work.
Here is a simple solution I found accidently.
I have a Logitec dongle for wireless keyboard and mouse. I removed it. Now Windows Explorer does not crash when I click on the USB drive in Windows Explorer.
I don't know what is the issue. Blame Logitec.